Creating a grid with same cell size but image can take multiple cells?
I thought I am trying to do something simple, but I can't figure out how to do it.
I will provide the playground link at the end: I want to create a grid like view where we have a given amount of cells. In my example I have the row and cols amount defined at the top.
With that I have an items array and want to place them by x,y in the grid.
IF an item has width or height greater than 1, it should take more cells -> w=2 means 2 cells.
In some solutions I have the same item multiple times in the array but I couldn't figure out how to group, later I have a new array with placeholders which also seems weird.
I tried to solve this with flex, grid and tables, have all my "ideas" in one playground that you see what I tried. I even tried different ideas in filling the array, but I suppose that's not a solution.
I commented all ideas, nearly all the time the "spanning" isn't working, or if you check the last two it's creating more rows, but it... shouldn't. IF you need more information, please write.
Here is a svelte playground - you can find 6 ideas below each other separated by === and comments:
https://svelte.dev/repl/4680996be33d4c429d1c0eedf8f0b6a5?version=4.2.15
(I noticed that the grid doesn't work in the playground on initial click, so just enter a space in the editor, then it's loading correctly).
I hope somebody can give me a working solution. It doesn't have to be responsive, but ideal it should be smaller but that's probably a problem for later, for now the spanning is just broken and I can't figure out why...
I actually want to understand the problem and the solution, so just using a grid library isn't my goal here. I also don't need drag & drop functionality.
Grid idea:
   <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 grid-flow-col">
    {#each grid as row, i}
        <div>
            {#each row as item, j}
                {#if item}
                    <!-- style here not working as it's not a child of grid -->
                    <div class="grid h-10 border border-gray-300" style="grid-column: span {item.w || 1}; ; grid-row: span {item.h || 1};">
                        <img src={icon}>
                        <!-- {item.name} -->
                    </div>
                {:else}
                    <div class="grid h-10 border border-gray-300"></div>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>

Table idea:
<table class="table-fixed w-full h-full">
{#each gridTable as row, i}
    <tr>
        {#each row as item, j}
            {#if item && item.name === 'empty'}
                <td class="h-10 border border-gray-300">
                    <div class="h-full w-full border border-gray-200"></div>
                </td>
            {:else if item}
                <td colspan={item.w} rowspan={item.h} class="relative border border-gray-300" style="background-image: url({icon}); background-size: cover;">
                    <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
                       {item.name} {item.x},{item.y}
                    </div>
                </td>
            {/if}
        {/each}
    </tr>
{/each}
</table>

Oh, and I tried to fill the grid either with:
function createGrid2() {
    for (let item of items) {
        grid[item.x][item.y] = item;
    
        for (let i = item.y ; i < item.y + item.h; i++) {
            for (let j = item.x ; j < item.x + item.w; j++) {
                grid[j][i] = item;
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;
}

or
function createGridNull() {
    for (let item of items) {
        gridNull[item.x][item.y] = item;
        
        for (let i = item.y; i < item.y + item.h; i++) {
            for (let j = item.x; j < item.x + item.w; j++) {
                if (i !== item.y || j !== item.x) {
                    gridNull[j][i] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return gridNull;
}


Please [edit] your question in order to include the (relevant) code of your best attempt(s) here in the question (see the "[mcve]" guidance, and also the hints on how to add a running "stack snippet"). I know you've linked to code elsewhere, but the essential code to reproduce your problem is required to be in the question itself (to prevent users being sent to questionable websites, to guard against link-rot, to minimise the time necessary to provide answers and/or reproduce your scenario).

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

If you have exact coordinates, you can directly position elements at the desired location. If you also want to somehow fill the leftover cells, those would probably need to be determined programmatically based on the existing items.
<div class="grid gap-4 grid-cols-12 auto-rows-fr">
    {#each items as item}
        <div class="grid border border-gray-300"
            style="
                grid-column: {item.x} / span {item.w ?? 1};
                grid-row: {item.y} / span {item.h ?? 1};
            ">
            <div class="min-h-10">{item.name}</div>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>

REPL
Example of filling with empty cells:
const height = 12;
const width = 12;
$: leftoverCells =
    height * width
    - items.map(x => x.h * x.w).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

<!-- additional loop after actual items -->
{#each { length: leftoverCells } as _}
    <div class="h-10 border border-gray-500"></div>
{/each}

REPL

Thank you, your second link is actually a really good solution. I wasn't aware that there is a dense property.

Actually, here you don't even need dense flow since the filler items are all one cell large. If you e.g. were to auto-flow the regular odd-sized items and try to not leave gaps, you might need it.

dense flow example.

But now you don’t have any fillers?

That is just an example of dense, nothing else.
